# JavaFX and CSS: font wont't appear on Application

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts

Yesterday, I tried to embedd a custom font and it worked somehow, unfortunately I destroyed the git project because of a wrong clean command. So today, I cloned the repo on a different location and tried it again the exact same way like yesterday. It does not work. So I tried both loading a font directly in the resources folder and one in another folder that's in the resources folder called fonts

Here my CSS-File main.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Font";
    src: url("font-regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontnew";
    src: url("fonts/font.ttf");
}

.root {
    -fx-font-family: "Fontnew";
}
```

I get this stylesheet by

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("main.css");
```

And the application gets this stylesheet by 100% because other classes in the CSS-file that are responsible for hovering effects work and `System.out.println(scene.getStylesheets().add("main.css"));` says it's true in the console

Comment: _it worked somehow .. tried it again the exact same way like yesterday. It does not work_ you see the logical contradiction, do you ;) Or in other words: you certainly did a differently at that one location where it matters (most probably the resource /location lookup is broken). Nothing much we can do from here: it's you who has to find that location. In your shoes, I would try a new project doing nothing else than loading/using a custom font. And  provide a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected.

Comment: No, because yesterday font-regular worked!! then i installed the new font. i replaced url simply with "font.ttf", i did nothing else!! the 2 fonts were saved at the same location... font.ttf didnt work, but when i replaced font.ttf with font-regular.ttf again, it somehow showed font-regular again?? today NOTHING works

Comment: so the change was to replace the font you used yesterday by another font? That's not exactly _the exact same_ ;) Anyway, please read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Main.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).